# React/ Express Login with localstorage token redirect issues

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So I'm certain there is something small that is missing or that I just do not understand about React. I have a react frontend sitting on an express/mongoose backend. Upon login, an 'authToken' gets set in the local storage (which is working fine), then it should redirect through the home route "/" which calls a private route component to just verify the authToken before redirecting to the user's dashboard page. Upon landing at the dashboard page, another call goes out to run through the middleware to decode the authToken and find the correct user.

My issue is coming in during the login redirecting to next steps, and I've tried using history.push("/private") and Redirect component.
Heres the login screen's onSubmit:

```
onSubmit={async (values) => {
    
          
                     
          await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth/login', values)      
          .then(response => {
            
            console.log(response.data);
            
            localStorage.setItem("authToken", response.data.token);
            //return response.data;
            

          })
          .then( 
            //history.push("/")
            <Redirect to="/" />
              
          )
          
          .catch(function (error){
            console.log(error);
          });
          
          
          
        }}
```

The private route to verify the authToken:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ ...rest}) => {
  
    

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            component={(props) => 
                    localStorage.getItem("authToken") ? (
                        <Redirect to="/dashboard" {...props} />
                    ) : (
                        <Redirect to="/login" />
                    )
                }
        />
    );

    
};
```

And the Dashboard call to decode the auth token and find the user:

```
const fetchUserData = async () => {
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("authToken")}`
                },
            }
            

            try {
                const {data} = await axios.get("/private", config);
                setUserData(data.data);

            } catch (error) {
                localStorage.removeItem("authToken");
                setError("You are not authorized, please login")

                history.push("/login")

            }
        }

        fetchUserData();
    }, []);
```

Previously I was getting a bad call when the dashboard called to get the user with the post call showing the Authorization header with Bearer null, even when the authToken showed in the storage. Not sure how I fixed that aspect since it was not anything that directly affected how the header should have been getting sent with the call. Now with either redirecting method, the console logs the success, the token is displayed and also shows in the localstorage, but no further network calls go out, no redirection. If I refresh the page, I get the dashboard component and in the network the calls to the middleware go through fine.

```
console log
Object { success: true, token:'some token here'}
```

Network log
[image: network log before page refresh]

and the full page loading with a clean network call after the page refresh

[image]

So I guess my issue is with how I'm redirecting? I'm out of ideas on why the redirect doesnt go through until I refresh the page, with everything going through fine after. Sorry for the long post, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can tell, what is happening is the .then( history.push("/") is not being reached-to trigger the re-render. Since I can't put a return or render statement in the promise, I'm at a loss of how else to try and tackle it.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by simply moving the history.push into the initial .then() statement of the promise. No idea why that worked, or why it worked for the tutorial I followed in the way I originally had set it up. Clearly something I'm not getting about promises. If anyone sees this and understands why that simple move made the difference, I'd appreciate the insight.

My only guess is that the second .then() clause was missing a function to provide a return to? I attempted to force the return in a couple different ways, but eslint said no, and eventually ended up with the solution of just moving history.push() to the initial .then(). Reading below, I'm still not certain why it did not work in the initial set-up, or why for that matter it worked in the tutorial and in some other examples online.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises